# what kind of data encryption is using Default Databricks file system or Default DBFS or DBFS root?

Tags: azure, encryption, filesystems, azure-storage, azure-databricks

Azure databricks Allows to mount storage objects so I cant easily mount Azure storage(Blob,Data Lake), and I know  Azure storage using 256-bit AES encryption.

But my question is when I store my data or save my data in Default Databricks file system or DBFS root(Not mount point) is it use any kind of encryption system or not?
[image]

Any help appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data in Azure Storage (Azure Databricks DBFS resides in Blob storage which is created while creating databricks workspace called as Managed Resource Group) is encrypted and decrypted transparently using 256-bit AES encryption.

Azure Databricks File System DBFS is an abstraction layer on top of Azure Blob Storage which is created in the Managed Resource Group that lets you access data as if it were a local file system.

[image]

By default, when you deploy Databricks it creates Azure Blob Storage that is used for storage and can be accessed via DBFS. When you mount to DBFS, you are essentially mounting a Azure Blob Storage/ADLS Gen1/Gen2 to a path on DBFS.

[image]

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

---

Do click on "Mark as Answer" and Upvote on the post that helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: Thanks @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT for your answer. I think i got my ans , just a quick summary 
When I deploy Databricks it creates Azure Blob Storage that is used for storage that we call 'Root' and it using 256-bit AES encryption.
Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.